# Apache Spark: RDD[Char] but should be RDD[String] as result of flatmap

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I'm basically doing this

```
// data type

  type FeatureTuple = ((String, String), Double)


featureTuple.flatMap(_._1._2)
```

But it's returning a RDD[Char] and not RDD[String], why would this happen?

Comment: What do you get with `flatMap(_._1)` and `flatMap(_._2)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flatMap` is causing the `String` to be implicitly converted to a `WrappedString` which is a `TraversableOnce[Char]` (because the `flatMap` method of `RDD` is expecting an argument of type `T => TraversableOnce[U]` and a `String` can be converted into a `TraversableOnce[Char]`), and so you will end up with a `RDD[Char]` instead of an `RDD[String]`. If that implicit conversion did not exist (it is defined in `scala.Predef`), then you'd just get a compile error.

Anyway, to fix this just use `map` instead of `flatMap`.